# Remote Access of Ipad

Tags: ipad

How can I access my elderly mothers iPad for teaching and troubleshooting purposes, while using my mac from many miles away. I have done some reading and found I-Keyboard and Airplay as possible solutions. Can anyone assist with which of these solutions is viable?

Comment: Take a look at [this list of guidelines](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation?noredirect=1&lq=1) to use when requesting a software recommendation. This will help everyone make sure whatever is recommended meets your needs and hasn't already been tried.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have a MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2010) running OS X El Capitian v-10.11.6.